# Trouble with touchpad&mouse scroll

Tags: touchpad, synaptics, mouse-scroll, hp-touchpad

I have notebook HP compaq 6720s with ubuntu 14.04. Mouse scroll work ok, but scroll on touchpad is reversed. I trying to configurate touchpad in Ubuntu tweak, result: touchpad scroll works ok, but mouse scroll is reversed. How i can make both scrolls work normally? tpconnfig is installed, my touchpad is Synaptics.

```
sudo tpconfig

Found Synaptics Touchpad.
Firmware: 8.96 (multiple-byte mode).
```